# Replace text with sequence of numbers

Tags: bash, terminal, text, replace

I have 2250 metadata files that need to have a unique number starting at 0 going to 2249, as the line below.

`"name": "KF # RENUMBER",`

I've used the perl command (perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.json) to replace a word with whatever I need in multiple files, but I can't figure out how instead of replacing it with a word, replacing it with the numbers so at the end of the day I have multiple files that have a line like:

```
"name": "KF # 1",
"name": "KF # 2",
...
"name": "KF # 2249",
```

I tried `perl -pi -w -e 's/RENUMBER/$count++;/g;' *.json`

but that returned `"name": "KF # ++;",` in all the files

I'm using terminal in MacOS to do this, if that is important.

any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Perl that the replacement part is not a string but some code to run:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/RENUMBER/++$count/ge' *.json
#                                    ^
```

"e" is for "evaluate".

Also, if you want to start from 1 and not 0, switch to `++$count`.

You can also increment the variable outside of the substitution.

```
perl -i~ -pwe '++$count; s/RENUMBER/$count/' *.json
```

This behaves differently if there's more than one RENUMBER per line (the previous replaces each with a different number, this one uses the same number for the whole line). I assumed there's never more than one RENUMBER per line and therefore I removed the `/g`.

Comment: I used the first instance and it worked great. I was really dreading the tedious task of renumbering over 2000 files so I can't tell you how much I appreciate the help from both who answered.

btw, I just took file #0 and edited that manually. just for sake of knocking it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `e` flag to your `s//` expression, which tells perl to evaluate the replace part as an expression:

```perl
perl -pi -w -e 's/RENUMBER/$count++;/ge;' *.json
```

Given three files `data{1,2,3}.json` each containing:

```
{
"name": "KF # RENUMBER",
}
```

Running the above command results in:

```
$ grep -n . *json
data1.json:1:{
data1.json:2:"name": "KF # 0",
data1.json:3:}
data2.json:1:{
data2.json:2:"name": "KF # 1",
data2.json:3:}
data3.json:1:{
data3.json:2:"name": "KF # 2",
data3.json:3:}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! got exactly what I needed